# Looping over ajax requests in a chrome extension, not working

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I was trying loop over the ajax request continuously but it was doing the ajax thing only for the last loop.

```
while(i<3){
var query = site_url+keywords[i]+'"' ;
         $.ajax({
            url: query,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "html"
success: function(html) {
var el = $(html).find("#tagID");
                    if(el.length) {
                        console.log("Element  exists");  
                        var cont = 1;

                    }
else{
console.log("Element  doesnt exist");
 var cont = 0;
}
}
});
        console.log(cont);

        i=i+1;    
        }
```

Comment: Also if you can please explain what you are trying to do - do you want to find out whether any of the three pages contain this element? Do you want to open pages in parallel or one after another? etc

Comment: @serg hi, i want to save the keywords for which the element exists. save a seperate array or something. possible?

Comment: You will have index of a keyword that was found, so inside `result()` method you can get the found keyword with `keywords[i]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along those lines:

```
processKeyword(0);

function processKeyword(i) {
    if(i < keywords.length) {
        var query = site_url+keywords[i]+'"' ;
        $.ajax({
            url: query,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "html"
            success: function(html) {
                var el = $(html).find("#tagID");
                if(el.length) {
                    //found, stop processing
                    result(i);
                } else{
                    //not found, process next
                    processKeyword(i + 1);
                }
            }
        });

    } else {
        //all processed, nothing found
        result(-1);
    }

}

function result(i) {
    //i contains keyword index if was found, -1 otherwise
}
```